# SOAP Web Service accessing with PHP, need a blank Header

Tags: php, soap, sap-basis

this is what I generate using the SoapClient PHP class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:_-bic_-nf2>
   <ETColumnDescription/>
   <ETGridData/>
   <ETMessageLog/>
   <ETRowDescription/>
   <ISVar_01xwerbet>
    <Sign>I</Sign>
    <Option>LE</Option>
    <Low>3</Low>
    <High/>
   </ISVar_01xwerbet>
  </ns1:_-bic_-nf2>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I also need is a blank header which should look like `<SOAP-ENV:Header/>` 
right before `<SOAP-ENV:Body>`

But doing it with SOAPHeader: `$header = new SOAPHeader('urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style',null,null)` doesnt seem to be working. Tried everything. Any other ideas?

What I also need is, to remove the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` before sending the request, I think the server doesn't like it, would that be possible?

If it helps, this is for a SAP Web Service.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Just refer the nusoap.php file in libraries. You can modify the header which is normally present under the variable $headers.
I tried and it worked for me.